# For mobile automation (Robotium or UIAutomation) is it better to have all tests in one class or to split by feature

Tags: java, javascript, robotium, ios-ui-automation

I have a lot of tests in the same class, and some people tell me is better to have it this way because when we integrate with the server, those tests can be accessed more easily.
But i think that when i will need to maintain those tests, it will be hard for me to go through 2-300 methods.

Therefore i am trying to see what are the pros and cons for each of these 2 scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I guess JUnit is the best framework for managing and maintaining your tests.
You should split all tests by specific attribute and group them in different classes. After that you'll create a test suit class with JUnit which joins all classes. At last you'll write a TestRunner class using JUnit again

See an examples here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

Pros of separate methods:

- You can run them selecting the methods you're interested in.
- You've a report for each one so you can easily understand where the test failed